# Персистентные соединения. Сервера и типы соединений

Tags: сервер

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь разобраться с наиболее распространенными типами соединений. В частности с ***персистентными*** соединениями. 
 Под словом "помочь" я подразумеваю ссылки на источники с **хорошей**, **понятой** выкладкой информации, *не важно в каком виде.*  
Простые примеры может быть с комментариями.

И да, я гуглил. Но хорошего и понятного материала найти не сумел.
Спасибо всем кто подскажет!

Comment: Возможно просто нужно перевести это слово и все станет понятно? Персистентное соединение - это постоянное соединение, когда и сервер, и клиент в любой момент могут отправить/принять данные. Обычно это TCP и то, что базируется на нем. Но не совсем все:) HTTP - хоть и базируется, но обычно он не является персистентным.

Comment: А о чем именно идет речь, в смысле, на каком-то уровне OSI вы эти соединения изучаете или даже что-то конкретное и прикладное, связанное с `sql`-сервером или `apache`, например?

Comment: tcp, http. Пробую писать простейший echo- сервер на python.